# How do I pick elements of array that is inside another and put them on outside array in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array inside of another: `[['SUM','1'],['1']]`
and I would like to pick the `SUM` and the `1` elements and put them outside the array.

How can I do it?

Comment: By "outside" do you mean flattening them (to make it `['SUM', '1', ['1']]` or do you mean removing part of it to another variable, or what? Part of a [MCVE] is providing the desired output; your description is too vague to answer. Also, side-note: What you have is a `list`, not an array. Python has an `array` module, but it's special purpose, not at all what you're using.

Comment: it's better if you can showcase what's the current output and what's the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain

newlist = [x for x in chain(*[['sum','1'],['1']])]

print(newlist) #['sum', '1', '1']
```